# Avoid Zoom In/Out in Electron Browser Window

Tags: javascript, html, electron, electron-builder

I know there are other resources trying to solve this but none of them seem to have worked for me. I think this is because I'm using browser Window function. So all I need to do is avoid the zoom in/out in my electron application page when it's running a browser window. This is the main code of my browser window:

```js
const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1500,
    height: 1000,
    minWidth:1300,
    minHeight:700,
    Icon: "logo.ico"
 
  });
  mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)


  // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadURL("https://google.com")

  // mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.\
 // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

};
```

I tried using the following methods but they all failed:

```
const { webFrame } = require('electron')

webFrame.setZoomFactor(2)


//also tried the following one but it failed


  const contents = mainWindow.webContents

contents.setZoomFactor(100)
```

Just an FYI I tried putting these codes in both rendered and main processes. Any help shall be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">` in your `html` file?

Comment: How about this;https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-frame#webframesetvisualzoomlevellimitsminimumlevel-maximumlevel